# Annotation to trim whitespaces on a variable in a DTO in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to create an annotation that will trim whitespace from an incoming JSON request when it's mapped to a DTO?

I would like to have it something like this:

```
public class TestDTO {
@TrimWhitespace
private String name;
...rest of the class
}
```

Or is there another good approach to easily trim whitespace from incoming data?

Answer (score 2):

The RequestBodyAdvice allows you to perform the functions you want.

RequestBodyAdvice.afterBodyRead works after ArgumentResolver so when you use RequestBodyAdvice, client's request already binded into DTO and you can modify it.

##### SampleController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class SampleController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> testMethod(@RequestBody TestDTO testDTO) {
        System.out.println(testDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testDTO);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/{var}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> testMethod(@RequestBody TestDTO testDTO, @PathVariable String var) {
        System.out.println(testDTO);
        System.out.println(var);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testDTO);
    }

    @Data
    public static class TestDTO {
        @TrimWhitespace
        private String trimName;
        private String nonTrimName;
        @TrimWhitespace
        private long longVal;
    }
}
```

##### SampleRequestBodyAdvice.java

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class SampleRequestBodyAdvice implements RequestBodyAdvice {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return methodParameter.getContainingClass() == SampleController.class && methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(RequestBody.class);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) throws IOException {
        return inputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        Field[] declaredFields = body.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            TrimWhitespace declaredAnnotation = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(TrimWhitespace.class);

            if (Objects.nonNull(declaredAnnotation)) {
                if (field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                    try {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(body, ((String) field.get(body)).trim());
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

##### Request

```
curl --location 'localhost:8080/test/123' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=B8DF3B174C95BE13FE5FC1FFAC40756E; WMONID=sQ3DIBp2iau' \
--data '{
    "trimName" : "   trimName   ",
    "nonTrimName" : "   nonTrimName   ",
    "longVal" : 123
}'
```

##### Response

```
{"trimName":"trimName","nonTrimName":"   nonTrimName   ","longVal":123}
```

** HandlerMethodArgumentResolver can do same function but you have to bind client's request into DTO.